# Azure REST api response has next link always as null

Tags: rest, azure

Azure Resource API's like Role Assignments 
(https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2015-07-01)
gives  a param called nextlink in the response.
But this is always null.
I tried adding 1010 Role assignments and still the nextlink is null.
Is there any limit on number of items returned in a single response or is nextlink just used for future enhancements?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we had the same problem - looking at the source of the Get-AzRoleAssignment cmdlet version 6.5.0 I can't see anything in the cmdlets that would support nextLink or skipToken.

So it's not implemented in the cmdlets - however there are other REST endpoints in Azure that support $top and those you can see they do correctly implement the nextLink property - you can see those working by setting $top to a lower number than your result set.

For example Policy Definitions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-definitions/list?view=rest-policy-2023-04-01&tabs=HTTP

For this you get a full URL on nextLink and you can just repeatedly call the GET REST command on nextLink until nextLink is empty and then you have the full dataset.

I can't see a way to predict whether Microsoft will implement nextLink on all (or more) resources in future so we are checking nextLink for resources that don't currently support it and throwing an exception if it's there.