# Azure roleassignment list not fetching full list

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

I am using REST API to fetch all role assignments at subscription scope. I don't have the nextLink and still don't have full list of role assignments. 
I noticed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546128/azure-rest-api-response-has-next-link-always-as-null) has no replies either. So looking for any help with resolution on this. I used URL:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/ID/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments. The missing ones were Owner role assigned to 2 users. Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this problem. The API does not have a flag like PowerShell to pass the IncludeClassAdministrators. So it misses the Service Administrator and CoAdministrator in the list. To workaround a separate call can be made to get just the ClassicAdministrators.